# IN VBA is there a good way to receive WM_HOTKEY messages or any other way to simulate Excel's Application.OnKey

Tags: vba, winapi, powerpoint

quite a long post so tl;dr first:
**Is there a proper way to receive WM_HOTKEY messages in VBA or any other proper way to act on individual keyboard shortcuts to call your own subroutines?**

I am currently writing a little Add-In for Powerpoint* , that has it's own Ribbon but I would also like to be able to call subroutines by keyboard shortcuts. In an Excel Add-In I am using *Application.OnKey*, which sadly is not available in Powerpoint. (* personal use at work to enhance productivity; might want to share it with my team but no professional/commercial development)

After quite a bit of research into the Windows API, keyboard hooks and so on I ran into a whole lot of problems with every approach I tried.

**1. Keyboard Hook**
I first tried a keyboard hook that analyzes keyboard input and does *something* if a specific combination of buttons is pressed (like CTRL+L or something). Unfortunately, I ran into the same problem that is described here [Windows keyboard hook API in VBA causes infinite loop in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838395/windows-keyboard-hook-api-in-vba-causes-infinite-loop-in-powerpoint).

Basically the problem is that using a WH_KEYBOARD hook causes Powerpoint to crash if you input text in a dialog window of Powerpoint (e.g. when you try to name a new design of yours like described in the linked post). Maybe there is a referencing issue (window instance, hook callback etc.)?
This problem does not occur when I try a WH_CBT hook but that causes different problems. For example I could not switch through running applications while the hook was running (i.e. a click on the icons in the taskbar had no effect).

Since these were my first encounters with the Windows API's [SetWindowsHookExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#parameters) and all that comes with it, I ran into an impasse at that point.

**2. Register Hotkey**
The first approach also showed that it's already quite a task to correctly register the key combinations you want to use as shortcuts. That's what let me into looking into [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which is easy to setup. After quite some research into Windows's message queue I understood that I have to implement a mechanism to listen to the message queue and register WM_HOTKEY messages. 
I came up with something that basically works (see code below) but unfortunately slows Powerpoint down quite a bit, which seems to be caused by DoEvents and the never-ending loop I used for PeekMessage.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MOD_ALT = &H1
Private Const MOD_CONTROL = &H2
Private Const MOD_SHIFT = &H4
Private Const PM_REMOVE = &H1
Private Const WM_HOTKEY = &H312
Private Const KC = 104
Private Const KC_ALT = 105
Private Const KC_CTRL = 106
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

' Needed for MSG Structure
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type Msg
    hwnd As Long
    message As Long
    wParam As Long
    lParam As Long
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Private Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" ( _
                                ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                ByVal id As Long, _
                                ByVal fsModifiers As Long, _
                                ByVal vk As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal id As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PeekMessageA" ( _
                                lpMsg As Msg, _
                                ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, _
                                ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
                                ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Private bCancel As Boolean

Private Sub SetHotKey()
    Call RegisterHotKey(0, KC_ALT, MOD_ALT, VK_SNAPSHOT)
End Sub
Private Sub UnSetHotKey()
    Call UnregisterHotKey(0, KC_ALT)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessMessages()
    Dim message As Msg

    Dim ModHwnd As Long
    ModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)

    'loop until bCancel is set to True
    Do While Not bCancel
        'wait for a message
        WaitMessage
        'check if it's a HOTKEY-message
        If PeekMessage(message, 0, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY, PM_REMOVE) Then
            'here I would check which hotkey was triggered and execute a macro depending on which
            Call TestSub
            Debug.Print time(), "called"
        End If
        'let the operating system process other events
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Is there a proper way to receive WM_HOTKEY messages in VBA or any other proper way to act on individual keyboard shortcuts to call your own subroutines?**
I know there is a program called [Shortcut Manager for PowerPoint](http://officeoneonline.com/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html) which also has an SDK to implement it into your own Add-In so that might be what I end up with but would be more flexible to have your own code and not having to rely on 3rd-party software (also harder sell to the IT department).

Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information or code examples (for the keyboard hook approach or anything else).

Best regards

Philipp

Comment: Probably VBA isn't the best choice for this

Comment: Seems like it, yes. But I am not familiar with Office Add-In development in any other language nor would I know the language itself. So it would be quite a hurdle to learn - which I might do anyway at one point. I work in Finance and started with an Excel Add-in for more productivity (especially with the keyboard) for which VBA is pretty much sufficient and I just wanted to port some functionality to Powerpoint. i then suddenly realized that there is no Application.OnKey to bind keyboard shortcuts - which then made me do quite some research and led me into this trial and error journey.

Comment: You aren't going to get anywhere trying to pump messages in VBA code. And there's no shortcut for this sort of low level hackery. You are not likely to stumble on a solution with first gaining the in depth winapi and office knowledge.

Comment: Thank for telling me how it is. I will then stop looking into the RegisterHotkey approach. I might keep looking into the keyboard hook approach but I think you are absolutely right about this being a task that requires better knowledge about the winapi. To lead me into the right direction: Do you have any idea why a WH_KEYBOARD hook crashes Powerpoint (basically freezes it) when writing in a dialog window (like also described in the linked post)?
Even if I could get it to work would you advise against it?

Comment: WH_KEYBOARD is a hook that requires a dll injected into the target process. You aren't doing that. When I said that you need expertise in winapi, I meant it. You won't learn what you need to grasp all the details, by writing VBA. It's the wrong tool for the job.